If I rip and scrutinize a frozen food box, and it doesn't seem to have any thin plastic coating, can I recycle it?
Here in Toronto, the city categorically says that frozen food packaging is non-recyclable, and should go in the garbage.
From what I've read, the problem with frozen food packaging is that it's "polycoat".  The term "polycoat" refers to cardboard coated in a very thin layer of plastic.  If you rip it slowly and look closely, you can see:  The paper rips first, and the plastic rips next.  See, for example, this source.
Many cities don't accept polycoat frozen food boxes for recycling.  (Some cities might accept polycoat milk, juice, and beverage cartons, but even these are difficult and expensive to recycle.)
On the other hand, I've seen some frozen food boxes which I've torn slowly and scrutinized, and which didn't seem to be polycoat.  They seemed to just be ordinary cardboard.  Can I recycle such packaging in Toronto?
(Crossposted to Reddit /r/recycling, here.)

Wet it, and see if it disintegrates
Most paper recycling relies on the fact that cardboard and paper disintegrates when wet. Frozen food boxes (and a few other products, like paper cups) are generally made from "Wet-strength cardboard". This is a cardboard meant to be resistant to condensation (especially with all the environment changes moving from the manufacturer to the home). If it were regular cardboard, any wetness would weaken it to the point of disintegrating.
There may not be a plastic liner. Wet-strength cardboard is generally made in a couple of different ways

The fibers are held together by a glue-like binding compound
The cardboard gets lined with wax or plastic

Thus if you're unsure if a particular cardboard packaging would be suitable, the best thing to do is to run an experiment: Place some or all of the packaging into a bowl of water for 10 or so minutes. If it disintegrates when you try to pick it up, or is easily torn, it's probably safe to go in the recycling bin.
